# Calculating fraction of area characterized with certain values?

Tags: arcmap, area

I have a rasater data with cell values of the following: missing, 1, 2, 3, 4, and 5

Now I need to find the fraction defined as (area with value 5)/(Sum of areas with values 1,2,3,4) for a certain polygon.

So I need to ignore missing values.

How do I do that in Arcmap?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your operations will ignore missing data anyway.

So each cell has an x and y resolution. So you know the size of the cells. This is constant across the raster (almost always).

Just just calculate the count of cells with 5 in a polygon and store this in the polygon. This is merely the count value in ArcGIS for an integer raster. Call this field *afive* (integer).Then multiply it by the cell area.

Now just calculate the count of cells with all other values in the polygon and store this in the polygon This is merely the count value in ArcGIS for an integer raster. Call this filed *aother*. (integer) Then multiply it by the cell area.

Create a new filed field called *answer* (double precision)

Then in the field calculator *answer = afive/aother*

You can achieve this in raster by clipping the raster to the polygon extent (extract by mask) the multiplying the counts by the values.

Some help

http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/raster-and-images/raster-dataset-attribute-tables.htm
http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/tables/making-field-calculations-making-simple-field-calc.htm

Comment: Thanks a lot! Do I need a projection before doing this?

Comment: no you likely do not